# java.time.DateTimeException: Hijrah date out of range

Tags: java

today I was discovering Java's 8 Hijrah Date, and I am trying to convert from Hijri date to gregorian date; I have been getting this error:

java.time.DateTimeException: Hijrah date out of range

```
    String repayDate = date.substring(0, 4)+"-"+date.substring(4, 6)+"-"+date.substring(6, 8);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(repayDate);
        Calendar cl=Calendar.getInstance();
        cl.setTime(inputDate);


        HijrahDate hDate=    HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(LocalDate.of(cl.get(1),cl.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cl.get(Calendar.DATE))); 


        return IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(hDate).toString() ;
```

the content of date is : 1400-01-01

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a DateFormat and a Calendar at all? `LocalDate.parse(repayDate)` would work just fine.

Comment: What is the content of `date`?

Comment: the content of date is : 1400-01-01

Comment: So you're trying to convert Gregorian 1 January 1400 CE to Hijra?  Or trying to convert Hijra 1 Muharram 1400 AH to Gregorian?

Comment: This is really the content of `date`? It should be `14000101`.

Comment: I am trying to convert 1 Muharram 1400 AH to Gregorian

Comment: Then I think your approach is probably wrong, because you're actually creating 1 January 1400 CE first.

Comment: Using `LocalDate.of(...)` is not even needed here.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use a `DateFormat` and a `Calendar` at all - if you can use the Java time API you should refrain from using the legacy API.

Here is a simple example that "works" with your input:

```
String date = "14000101";

TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd")
                                       .withChronology(HijrahChronology.INSTANCE)
                                       .parse(date);
HijrahDate hDate = HijrahDate.from(ta);

System.out.println("hDate = " + hDate);
System.out.println("Gregorian date = " + IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(hDate).toString());
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.  My answer is inferior to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your input date manually, then create a Hijrah date from it and convert it to Gregorian like this.

```
public static LocalDate hijrahToGregorian(String input){
    int year = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(4,6));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(6,8));

    HijrahDate hijrah = HijrahDate.of(year, month, day);
    return IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(hijrah);
}
```

Comment: *"You could parse your input date manually"* quite dangerous since OP doesn't even know how to format his `input` String correctly. He would try your method with his existing "1400-01-01", which won't work that good with your code.

Comment: @Tom true, but if you don't know what your input date format is, then no other method will be any better.

Comment: You can validate it or expect something else, like three int parameters.

Comment: Sure, but that's beyond the scope of the question.  OP wanted to know how to do the conversion.

Comment: Your answer still could tell him what String format you're expecting (the same as OPs code, I know, but he already uses an incorrect format).

Comment: You are welcome to write your own answer, if you don't like mine.

Comment: I should write my own answer, because you fail to properly explain your answer? Doesn't make much sense. But anyway, it makes also no sense to discuss this any further.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, assylias.. i just little polished it.

```
public static String convertToGregorian(String hijriDate) {
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
                .withChronology(HijrahChronology.INSTANCE)
                .parse(hijriDate);

        HijrahDate hDate = HijrahDate.from(ta);

        return  IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(hDate)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-YYYY"));
}
```